# Branch.io : how to follow conversion with a Branch link to my iOS and Android list of apps?

Tags: branch.io, fabric.io

I would like to do the following with Branch.io but I don't know if it is possible.

I want to create a Branch.io link that will redirect to my catalog of app. So, this link will redirect to:
- something like https://itunes.apple.com/artist/idXXXXX on iOS
- something like https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=MY_COMPANY_NAME on Android

Branch.io is implemented in all the apps of my catalog.

I want to add a 'catalog button' in all my apps that will send to my iOS catalog on iOS, and to my Android catalog on Android. The redirection will be done with my Branch universal link.

Some users will click on the button and install no app, others will install one or several apps.

My question is : is it possible to follow the installs after a click on my catalog button ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To confirm, you will have a catalog page in your primary app for both iOS and Android. Within this catalog page, you will have multiple Branch links that have different iOS and Android redirects corresponding to the multiple sub apps.

Unfortunately, you can only track the clicks on these Branch links. If you want to track the installs, you must integrate Branch into each of the individual apps as well, and use the Branch link associated with that app to track installs.